# obtaining the xml in XMLDOM object

Tags: javascript, xml, xmldom

I have loaded an xml file into xmldoc, and i changed some xml elements in the xmldoc, after I want to put the xml of the xmldoc into a textbox. I will explain by showing the code:

```
xmlDoc = loadXMLString(document.getElementById("xmlText").value);
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Machines")[0].childNodes[0];
x.nodeValue="myMachine";
xmlText.value = xmlDoc.?????;`
```

So with what function/field to replace the questions mark in the last line above?

Comment: What loadXMLString function are you using?  It is not a built in js function.